# Default Path Of C# Installation

Tags: c#, file-io, path, text-files

Hello what path should I specify when creating a text file on c#.

I want it to put at the installation folder of my application.

Because I have a code like this.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("what path to put?");
```

Comment: You should put in the user's local directory (AppData or MyDocuments).  The installation directories are usually reserved and are not friendly when the same machine is used by multiple user accounts.  Plus they are also restricted for writing to on most corporate / enterprise level machines.

Comment: I want it to write where the user specified the installation folder. for example he/she chooses C:/MyApplication My text file would write at that directory. After installing my program

Comment: Right - but please understand this goes against best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the path to the directory your application is installed in.  (Where the assembly is)

```
 string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)